# sales_order_save_after not being trigger?

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I am trying to set up an observer which would trigger a command upon order becoming complete. I have tried marking a couple of orders as complete my observer is not being triggered.

.xml in etc/modules

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <Test_ReviewRequestTrigger>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </Test_ReviewRequestTrigger>
</modules>
<global>
    <models>            
        <review_request_trigger>
            <class>Test_ReviewRequestTrigger_Model</class>
        </review_request_trigger>
    </models>
    <events>
        <sales_order_save_after>
            <observers>
                <review_request_trigger>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>Test_ReviewRequestTrigger_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>implementOrderStatus</method>
                </review_request_trigger>
            </observers>
        </sales_order_save_after>
    </events> 
</global>
</config>
```

config.xml in app/code/.../ReviewRequestTrigger/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <Test_ReviewRequestTrigger>
        <active>true</active>
        <codePool>local</codePool>
    </Test_ReviewRequestTrigger>
</modules>
</config>
```

Observer.php in `app/code/.../ReviewRequestTrigger/Model/Observer.php`

```
class Test_ReviewRequestTrigger_Model_Observer 
{
    public function implementOrderStatus($event)
    {
        Mage::log("hello", null, 'test_ReviewRequestTrigger.log');
        $order = $event->getOrder();
        $stateProcessing = $order::STATE_COMPLETE;
        // Only trigger when an order enters processing state.
        if ($order->getState() == $stateProcessing && $order->getOrigData('state') != $stateProcessing) { 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `Oberver.php`? Are you sure about the name (missing `s`)? Please specify full path. Also did you clear cache?

Comment: I had miss spelt it in the text.

Comment: How are you sure that method is not executing?

Comment: I have added a logger in the file: `Mage::log("hello", null, 'test_ReviewRequestTrigger.log');`. After shipping and sending an invoice, within the order - order status changed to completed but I didn't find a log file within `/var/log`

Comment: Does the file exist and has the right permissions? Remove the other parameters and check for `system.log`.

Answer (score -1):

There are a couple of mistakes in your `config.xml` file that are the likely culprit(s).  Here is a link for more information on [how to set up an observer](https://www.pierrefay.com/magento-training/event-observer.html), but below is the relevant code as it applies to your question:

```
<events>
    <sales_order_save_after>
        <observers>
            <ReviewRequestTrigger>
                <type>singleton</type>
                <class>ReviewRequestTrigger/observer</class>
                <method>implementOrderStatus</method>
            </ReviewRequestTrigger>
        </observers>
    </sales_order_save_after>
</events>
```

Note the changes to the `<ReviewRequestTrigger>` wrapper and `<class>` tag within it.

Comment: `<class>` can contain both notations. That's not the problem here.

Comment: @revo, that is true, but the OP included `Test` in the class, but not in the tag around it.  It could alternatively be `<Test_ReviewRequestTrigger>` and `<class>Test_ReviewRequestTrigger_Model_Observer</class>`.  The original `<review_request_trigger>` is pointing to a class that doesn't exist.  I only did it the way I did because it is best practice.  [See the comments in this post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/41280/33071)

Comment: That surrounding tag name doesn't play an important rule here. It could be anything.